# Wordpress custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, post-meta

hello i have post_type "product" and taxonomy "price"
can someone help me to query that custom post type with the selected taxonomy?

my current code is like this

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$args = array(
 'post_type'   => 'product',
 'posts_per_page' => 5,
 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'productcategories',
      'terms' => $term->name
    )
  )
 );
 query_posts($args);
 print_r($args);
 ?>
```

but nothing on result, can someone help me? thank you

Comment: your taxonomy is `price` but you are querying `productcategories`?

Comment: my taxonomy is productcategories it like categories on normal post and i have several on taxonomy productcategories, price, area, etc this is like i have category price on normal post. i need to query depends on that productcategories term name on specific pages @Milo

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. Use `WP_Query` instead

Answer (score 0):

change your **$args** array to the following

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'productcategories',
            'terms'    => $term->name,
            'field'    => 'name'

        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'price',
            'terms'    => $term->name,
            'field'    => 'name'

        ),
    ),
);

$allproducts = new WP_Query($args);
```